# Use php regex to inset a character (+) in place of a space in a line

Tags: php, regex

I cant seem to figure out a way to just replace spaces with a plus sign.

Here is a simple example: http://regex101.com/r/vJ8uR6/3

The attempt is to turn these lines:

Into:
this+is+line+0+test
this+is+line+1+test

Regex: /(.+[^\s])/
Substitution: \1+

Any help is greatly appreciated!

---

### Also tried this but does not work: regex101.com/r/vJ8uR6/4

More clarification on example,
I actually want to place that string within another like so:
www.myurl.com/"The above strings with + in place of space"/someotherpath

Here is the new example: http://regex101.com/r/vJ8uR6/8

Comment: have you tried `str_replace()`?

Comment: on a more regex constructive note, you're searching for "any sequence of 1 or more characters that is then **not** followed by a space character" so you probably want to turn that `[^\s]` into `\s`. That said, there is no reason to use regex in PHP for this, as per everyone else's answers =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\h` matches any horizontal whitespace character. To match one or more horizontal whitespace character then you need to use `\h+`

Regex:

```
\h
```

Replacement string:

```
+
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/vJ8uR6/5)

Comment: Works but my initial question was faulty for what I need, I updated the question with new example, sorry: http://regex101.com/r/vJ8uR6/8

Comment: No exactly because each line will have a different number of words with spaces. Since this seems a little more difficult than I though to do it with regex, I am doing some link making tasks manually by first using your example to add + (http://regex101.com/r/vJ8uR6/5), then paste all that in here to convert it to url: http://regex101.com/r/vJ8uR6/10.  Thanks for Everyones quick help with this!

Answer (score 1):

You just want to replace spaces (`/ /`) with plus signs (`/+/`).

Your example, changed to reflect that: http://regex101.com/r/vJ8uR6/6

Comment: Works but my initial question was faulty for what I need, I updated the question with new example, sorry: http://regex101.com/r/vJ8uR6/8

Answer (score 1):

To do that you don't need a regex:

```
$result = strtr($str, ' ', '+');
```

If your goal is to perform a replacement in a specific column of a table:

```
UPDATE yourtable SET yourcol=REPLACE(yourcol, ' ', '+');
```

To add something at the begining and at the end:

```
UPDATE yourtable SET yourcol=CONCAT('http://my_domain.com/', REPLACE(yourcol, ' ', '+'), '/pathend');
```

Comment: Sorry, Im not sure I can use this in phpmyadmin query but i do have a regex tool I can use.

Comment: @user1745382: in this case you can use a SQL query.